# Parsing a dictionary text file in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, search, text-files

I am using ruby to try and parse a text file that has the form...

```
AAB eel bbc 
ABA did eye non pap mom ere bob nun eve pip gig dad nan ana gog aha
    mum sis ada ava ewe pop tit gag tat bub pup
    eke ele hah huh pep sos tot wow aba ala
    bib dud tnt 
ABB all see off too ill add lee ass err xii ann fee vii inn egg odd bee dee goo
    woo cnn pee fcc tee wee ebb edd gee ott ree vee ell orr rcc att boo cee cii
    coo kee moo mss soo doo faa hee icc iss itt kii loo mee nee nuu ogg opp pii
    tll upp voo zee
```

I need to be able to search by the first column, such as "AAB",and then search through all values that are associated with that key.  I have tried to import the text file into a hash of arrays but could never get more than the first value to store.  I have no preference as to how I can search the file, whether that is store the data into some data structure or just search the text file every time, I just need to be able to do it.  I am at a loss as to how to proceed with this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

-amc25114

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will read your dictionary file. I'm storing the content in a string, then
turning it into a StringIO object to let me pretend it's a file. You can use
[`File.readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines) to read directly from the file itself:

```
require 'pp'
require 'stringio'

text = 'AAB eel bbc 
ABA did eye non pap mom ere bob nun eve pip gig dad nan ana gog aha
    mum sis ada ava ewe pop tit gag tat bub pup
    eke ele hah huh pep sos tot wow aba ala
    bib dud tnt 
ABB all see off too ill add lee ass err xii ann fee vii inn egg odd bee dee goo
    woo cnn pee fcc tee wee ebb edd gee ott ree vee ell orr rcc att boo cee cii
    coo kee moo mss soo doo faa hee icc iss itt kii loo mee nee nuu ogg opp pii
    tll upp voo zee
'

file = StringIO.new(text)

dictionary = Hash[
  file.readlines.slice_before(/^\S/).map{ |ary| 
    key, *values = ary.map(&:strip).join(' ').split(' ')
    [key, values] 
  }
]
```

`dictionary` is a hash looking like:

```
{
  "AAB"=>[
    "eel", "bbc"
  ],
  "ABA"=>[
    "did", "eye", "non", "pap", "mom", "ere", "bob", "nun", "eve", "pip",
    "gig", "dad", "nan", "ana", "gog", "aha", "mum", "sis", "ada", "ava",
    "ewe", "pop", "tit", "gag", "tat", "bub", "pup", "eke", "ele", "hah",
    "huh", "pep", "sos", "tot", "wow", "aba", "ala", "bib", "dud", "tnt"
  ],
  "ABB"=>[
    "all", "see", "off", "too", "ill", "add", "lee", "ass", "err", "xii",
    "ann", "fee", "vii", "inn", "egg", "odd", "bee", "dee", "goo", "woo",
    "cnn", "pee", "fcc", "tee", "wee", "ebb", "edd", "gee", "ott", "ree",
    "vee", "ell", "orr", "rcc", "att", "boo", "cee", "cii", "coo", "kee",
    "moo", "mss", "soo", "doo", "faa", "hee", "icc", "iss", "itt", "kii",
    "loo", "mee", "nee", "nuu", "ogg", "opp", "pii", "tll", "upp", "voo", "zee"
  ]
}
```

You can look up using the keys:

```
dictionary['AAB']
=> ["eel", "bbc"]
```

And search inside the array using `include?`:

```
dictionary['AAB'].include?('eel')
=> true
dictionary['AAB'].include?('foo')
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A

  def initialize
    @h, key = readlines.inject({}) do |m, s|
      a = s.split
      m[key = a.shift] = [] if s =~ /^[^\s]/
      m[key] += a
      m
    end
  end

  def lookup k, v # not sure what you really want to do here
    p [k, v, (@h[k].index v)]
  end

  self
end.new.lookup 'ABA', 'wow'
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
file = File.open("/path_to_file_here")
recent_key = ""
results = Hash.new
while (line = file.gets)
  key = line[/[A-Z]+/]
  recent_key = key if key
  line.scan(/[a-z]+/).each do |val|
    results[recent_key.to_sym] = [] if !results[recent_key.to_sym]
    results[recent_key.to_sym] << val
  end
end
puts results
```

This will give you this ouput:

```
{

:AAB=>["eel", "bbc"], 

:ABA=>["did", "eye", "non", "pap", "mom", "ere", "bob", "nun", "eve", "pip", "gig", "dad", "nan", "ana", "gog", "aha", "mum", "sis", "ada", "ava", "ewe", "pop", "tit", "gag", "tat", "bub", "pup", "eke", "ele", "hah", "huh", "pep", "sos", "tot", "wow", "aba", "ala", "bib", "dud", "tnt"],

 :ABB=>["all", "see", "off", "too", "ill", "add", "lee", "ass", "err", "xii", "ann", "fee", "vii", "inn", "egg", "odd", "bee", "dee", "goo", "woo", "cnn", "pee", "fcc", "tee", "wee", "ebb", "edd", "gee", "ott", "ree", "vee", "ell", "orr", "rcc", "att", "boo", "cee", "cii", "coo", "kee", "moo", "mss", "soo", "doo", "faa", "hee", "icc", "iss", "itt", "kii", "loo", "mee", "nee", "nuu", "ogg", "opp", "pii", "tll", "upp", "voo", "zee"]

}
```